# for loop that will iterate through a file that is given and add 200 to C_x each time

Tags: python, for-loop

```
      for i in range(0,len(new)):
            if '-D' in new[i]:
                core_count = core_count + 1
                print(core_count)
                if(core_count % 2) == 0:
                    print('true')
                    txt.write("\n")
                    if(core_count == 2):
                        C_x = C_x

                    else:
                        for(core_count > 2):
                            C_x = C_x + 200
                            print(C_x)
```

I want a for loop after the else that will add 200 to C_x after each iteration of the given file for when C_x is greater than 2 & even

Answer (score 0):

```
...
if core_count==2:
    C_x=C_x
if core_count>2:
    C_x+=200
...
```

There is no need for a `for` loop after the `else`.

Comment: Or am i missing something? Why do you need a for loop after your 'else' statement?

Comment: Though, what is the meaning of 'C_x=C_x' i do not understand also.

Comment: This worked for me, C_x is declared as 0 earlier in the code

Comment: If C_x was set to 0, it stays that way until it is re-set.